# How to Avoid Javascript in Facebook Post Description Text?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I added some js for website tesing in the first sentences of my website. Facebook shows this js in the post description. How can I avoid that the Javascript is shown in the Facebook Post Description Text?

Comment: do a search for Facebook Open Graph tags

Comment: I do have opengraph tags set

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to sanitize the content. There are tons of ways to do it. Here's a JS lib i've used before: [Sanitize.js](https://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js)